# How to load a text file to a string variable in java

Tags: java, eclipse, text-files, java.util.scanner, stdin

I'm pretty new in the programming world, and i can't find a good explanation on how to to load a txt file to a string variable in java using eclpise.

So far, from what i have been able to understand, i am supposed to use the StdIn class, and i know that the txt file need to be located in my eclipse workspace (outside the source folder) but i don't know what excatly i need to write in the code to get the given file to load into the variable.

I could really use some help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I'm not a Java expert, I'm pretty sure [this is the information you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-do-i-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file) It looks like this:

```
static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding)
  throws IOException
{
  byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
  return new String(encoded, encoding);
}
```

Basically all languages provide you with some methods to read from the file system you're in. Hope that does it for you!

Good luck with your project!

Comment: To put into String's, the OP should use ``String[] Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path))``.

Comment: `Files.readString` will do all this in one call (added in Java 11).

Answer (score 1):

to read a file and store it in a `String` you can do it by using either `String` or `StringBuilder`:

1. you need to define `BufferedReader` to with constructor of `FileReader` to pass the name of the file and make it ready to read from file.
2. use `StringBuilder` to append every line of result to it.
3. when the reading finished add the result to `String` data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        data = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```